# Installing macOS Catalina onto brand new SSD

Tags: ssd, macbook-pro, macos-catalina

I'm fighting with a macbook with new ssd.
When I try to install mac os Catalina via online recovery, the installation fails.
It fails everytime at 2 minutes remaining with error "there was an error when preparing the installation. Restart the app.".

I tried to clean the nvram, and set the time via command line, but this doesn't help.

Does someone has an idea how to solve this?

Comment: Not really enough to work on. Make sure the drive is GUID/APFS. Catalina doesn't like HFS+ & no Mac will boot from an MBR volume.

Comment: Are you running into T2 problems? What model MacBook, exactly? Give us the "MacBookX,Y" designator from the system report.

Comment: Download the whole installation and install from USB.  That's what I did.

Comment: Exact same issue. And I AM using a bootable USB and GUID/AFPS. Did you solve the problem?